# redirect is working in some controllers and some not (same code) php and also in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am going crazy here, days trying to figure out why the re direct is working
in php and also in javascript in some controllers and some not
they are the same code and same view html code
the same ajax
the same form 
I tried with location href and also with php redirect 
it is not working
all methods in the function is working only the redirect or the json encode is the one that not working
and in the console of firebug it reveals that the "post" happen 
error shown TypeError: data is null

by the way this happens only when I write the right username and password
when I write wrong info 
error message appear Invalid Username or Password
and in console {"st":0,"msg":"Invalid Username or Password"}

the not working controller

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');

class signin_admin extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
}

public function index() {
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect('home');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('signin_admin_view');
    }
}

public function do_login() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[4]|max_length[20]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[4]|max_length[20]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $output = array('st' => 0, 'msg' => validation_errors());
        echo json_encode($output);
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
        );
        $result = $this->admin_model->login($data);
        if ($result == TRUE) {

            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $result = $this->admin_model->read_user_information($username);
            if ($result != false) {
                $session_data = array('user_id' => $result[0]->user_id,);
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in_admin', $session_data);
                $output = array('st' => 1);
                echo json_encode($output);
            }
        } else {
            $output = array('st' => 0, 'msg' => "Invalid Username or Password");

            echo json_encode($output);
        }
    }
}

}
```

the working controller

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');

class signin extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('user_model');
}

public function index() {
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect('home');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('signin_view');
    }
}

public function do_login() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[4]|max_length[20]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[4]|max_length[20]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $output = array('st' => 0, 'msg' => validation_errors());
        echo json_encode($output);
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
        );
        $result = $this->user_model->login($data);
        if ($result == TRUE) {

            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $result = $this->user_model->read_user_information($username);
            if ($result != false) {
                $session_data = array('user_id' => $result[0]->user_id, 'username' => $result[0]->username);
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);
                $output = array('st' => 1);
                echo json_encode($output);

            }
        } else {
            $output = array('st' => 0, 'msg' => "Invalid Username or Password");

            echo json_encode($output);
        }
    }
}

}
```

the ajax of the working controller and not working controller, the different is the location.href

```
<script src="public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#frm').submit(function(event){ 
$.post(
     $('#frm').attr('action'), 
     $('#frm').serialize(), 
     function(data) 
     {

     if (data.st == 0)
     {
     $('#validation-error').html(data.msg);
     }
           else if (data.st == 1)
     {
      window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('home'); ?>";
    }
     }, 
     'json'
   );
return false;   
});


});

</script>
```

model of admin (not working redirect)

```
public function login($data) {

$condition = "username =" . "'" . $data['username'] . "' AND " . "password =" . "'" . $data['password'] . "'";
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('admins');
$this->db->where($condition);
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
return true;
} else {
return false; 
}
}
```

Read user information function in users model (working)

```
public function read_user_information_profile($user_id) {

$condition = "user_id =" . "'" . $user_id . "'";
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where($condition);
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
return $query->result();
} else {
return false;
} 
}
```

Read user information function in admin model (not working controller)

```
public function read_user_information($user_id) {

    $condition = "user_id =" . "'" . $user_id . "'";
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('admins');
    $this->db->where($condition);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not shown code of user_model->**read_user_information**($username);

But after seeing your controller code, when **read_user_information($username)** returns false, there is no echoing of error. And this is the possible reason for TypeError: data is null.

To find the exact error, you have to modify the controller and jquery,

The modfied do_login() fn in controller:

```
public function do_login() {

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[4]|max_length[20]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[4]|max_length[20]');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    $output = array('st' => 0, 'msg' => validation_errors());
    echo json_encode($output);
} else {
    $data = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('password')
    );
    $result = $this->user_model->login($data);
    if ($result == TRUE) {

        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $result = $this->user_model->read_user_information($username);
        if ($result != false) {
            $session_data = array('user_id' => $result[0]->user_id, 'username' => $result[0]->username);
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);
            $output = array('st' => 1);
            echo json_encode($output);

        } else {
           $output = array('st' => 0, 'msg' => "Failed: read_user_information");
           echo json_encode($output);
        }
    } else {
        $output = array('st' => 0, 'msg' => "Invalid Username or Password");
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
}
}
```

And Jquery:

```
<script src="public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frm').submit(function(event){ 
    $.post(
         $('#frm').attr('action'), 
         $('#frm').serialize(), 
         function(retdata) 
         {
             // console.log(retdata);
             data = JSON.parse(retdata);
             if (data.st == 0)
             {
                 $('#validation-error').html(data.msg);
             }
             else if (data.st == 1)
             {
                  window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('home'); ?>";
             }
         }
       );
    return false;   
    });
    });

</script>
```

In case of any error just uncomment console.log(retdata); from jquery to see the real output and you can figure out what is wrong.

Comment: the problem is not when it get false, as false means wrong username or password and thats working
the problem happens when u write the right username and password
any way I have put the read user information model function
check them

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a slash '/' to the path in window.location.href  function also use the same in redirect. 
I am not 100% sure, but it worked for my friend.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was sending username to model function "read user information"
and this function was waiting user_id

```
public function read_user_information($user_id) {

$condition = "user_id =" . "'" . $user_id . "'";
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('admins');
$this->db->where($condition);
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
    return $query->result();
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```

and the working one now is

```
public function read_user_information($username) {

$condition = "username =" . "'" . $username . "'";
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('admins');
$this->db->where($condition);
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
    return $query->result();
} else {
    return false;
}
}
```